# A question about two structures

Tags: passive-voice, sentence-choice, gerund-clauses, participle-phrases

I've read in a grammar text that :

1. > I don't like people telling me what to do.
2. > I don't like being told what to do.

The author claimed that 1,2 convey same information in reader.

However, I think (1) is reduced version of the below sentence:

> I don't like people who are telling me what to do.

Which is implying "I dislike people" rather "I dislike their aptitude". Would you please shed light on my confusion ?

Beside, I want to know is it grammatically correct to use passive infinitive as:

3. > I don't like to be told what to do.

---

Edit:

Is there any difference between 2 and 3 ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that those two sentences have different meanings, exactly as you described. The last sentence is correct.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the explanation, yes, you're correct, there is a slight difference.  If you change the first sentence to

> I don't like people's telling me what to do.

it will change the meaning since the object to 'like' is now 'telling' and not 'people'.  However, I rarely hear or read that form.

As to your second inquiry, in some phrases verb-gerund can be swapped with verb-to-infinitive without the change in meaning.  Compare "*start to walk*" and "*start walking*" (and other with "begin" meaning), "*continue to think*" and "*continue thinking*", etc.  In your case it's "*like to be*" and "*like being*".